# web crawlering help required

Tags: web-crawler

hi i am completing a little hobby project of mine to create a small scale search engine.

i was wondering if any one knows of a decent robust opensource web crawler that they have used? it should be easy for a noob to setup and use.

thank you for not googling web crawlers and pasting a list .

Answer (score 2):

[crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) is a pretty decent crawler, multi-threaded and easy to configure and use. It's written in Java.

You can find a list of open-source crawlers in this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read a similar experience.

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html